# Customize a grid using tikz-euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide, grids

So I have the following code which makes use of the `tkz-euclide` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]
   \tkzGrid
   \tkzAxeXY
   \tkzDefPoint(1,1){E_{1, 1}}
   \tkzDefPoint(2,3){E_{2, 3}}
   \tkzDrawPoints(E_{1, 1}, E_{2, 3})
   \tkzLabelPoints(E_{1, 1}, E_{2, 3})
  \tkzText[above](0,6.75){A Sample Grid}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output

[image]

Now there are a few changes I'd like to make to this. Firstly I'd like to change the axes labels from "x" and "y" to "p" and "q".

Secondly, I'd like to label each point (p, q) on this grid as "E_{p, q}". I am not sure how I could do this in an efficient way. In any other programming language apart from LaTeX, I could use a for-loop to automate this process. Here, however, it seems that I would have to manually label all 175 points on this grid, something I do not look forward to doing.

How can I make these two changes to this grid?

---

**Update:** Following helpful comments below I produced the following tentative code to solve the second change I wanted to make, however there seems to be an error with it as it won't compile

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]
   \tkzGrid
   \tkzAxeXY
   \foreach\x in {-6,...,6}{
       \foreach\y in {-6,...,6}{
           \tkzDefPoint(\x,\y){E_{\x, \y}}
           \tkzDrawPoint(E_{\x, \y})
           \tkzLabelPoint(E_{\x,\y})
       }
   }
  \tkzText[above](0,6.75){A Sample Grid}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Am I on the right track, why doesn't the above code compile?

Comment: On the looping: `\foreach \x/\y in {1/1, 2/3}{\tikzDefPoint(\x,\y){E_{\x, \y}}}`

Comment: @Skillmon Wouldn't that only loop over the points (1, 1) and (2, 3)? I guess I might need a double for loop

Comment: Those are the two points you specified in your MWE, you can add more points to the first braced argument of `\foreach`, e.g., `\foreach \x/\y in {1/1, 2/3, 4/5, 6/7}{...}`.

Comment: @Skillmon I outlined why I wanted to avoid adding more points (in a fashion similar to that) in the last few paragraphs of my question as I'd have to manually add 175 points. Is there a way I could say basically `foreach \x` less than or equal to 6 and greater than or equal to -6 and `foreach \y`  less than or equal to 6 and greater than or equal to -6 `tikzDefPoint(\x, \y){E_{\x, \y}}`?

Comment: In that case you can use `\foreach\x in {-6,...,6}{\foreach\y in {-6,...,6}{<your code>}}`. The `...` in the `\foreach` arguments are parsed by Ti*k*Z as you want all the numbers in between the two end points. I misread your question in that the points are not always on grid points but could be arbitrary.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks for your helpful comments, I tried to write up some code which would achieve my second goal, (see the update in my question above) but it does not seem to be able to compile. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong in my use of the for loops in the updated code?

Comment: I'm no user of `tkz-euclide`, so I don't know whether you can use its macros in the loops like this and can't really help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `grid` and the loop `foreach` of TikZ are just perfect.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
%\pagecolor{yellow!25}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.28]
\draw[blue!50] (-6.5,-6.5) grid (6.5,6.5);
\draw[-stealth,thick] (-6.5,0)--(6.5,0) node[below right]{$p$}; 
\draw[-stealth,thick] (0,-6.5)--(0,6.5) node[above left]{$q$};
\foreach \i in {-6,...,-1,1,2,...,6}
\draw[very thick] 
(\i,.1)--(\i,-.1) node[below,fill=white]{\i}
(-.1,\i)--(.1,\i) node[right,fill=white]{\i};
\foreach \p in {-6,...,-1,1,2,...,6}
\foreach \q in {-6,...,-1,1,2,...,6}
\fill[red] (\p,\q) circle(2pt) node[below right,black]{$E_{\p,\q}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]
   \tkzGrid
    \tkzDrawX[label = $p$]
    \tkzDrawY[label = $q$]
    \tkzLabelXY
    \tkzDefPoint(1,1){E_{1, 1}}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,3){E_{2, 3}}
    \tkzDrawPoints(E_{1, 1}, E_{2, 3})
    \tkzLabelPoints(E_{1, 1}, E_{2, 3})
    \tkzText[above](0,6.75){A Sample Grid}

    \foreach \p in {-6,...,-1,1,2,...,6}
    \foreach \q in {-6,...,-1,1,2,...,6}
          { \tkzDefPoint(\p,\q){E_{\p, \q}}
            \tkzDrawPoint(E_{\p, \q})
             \tkzLabelPoints(E_{\p, \q}, E_{\p, \q})}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]